# Rabbitmq redirect based on headers value

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I have an exchange that is build like this:

```
{
  "name": "events_in_headers",
  "vhost": "/",
  "type": "headers",
  "durable": true,
  "auto_delete": false,
  "internal": false,
  "arguments": {}
}
```

Then I have three queues:

```
{
  "name": "events_queue_01",
  "vhost": "/",
  "durable": true,
  "auto_delete": false,
  "arguments": {}
},
{
  "name": "events_queue_02",
  "vhost": "/",
  "durable": true,
  "auto_delete": false,
  "arguments": {}
},

{
  "name": "events_queue_others",
  "vhost": "/",
  "durable": true,
  "auto_delete": false,
  "arguments": {}
}
```

And finally some bindings between queues and exchanges:

```
{
      "source": "events_in_headers",
      "vhost": "/",
      "destination": "events_queue_01",
      "destination_type": "queue",
      "routing_key": "#",
      "arguments": {
        "x-match": "all",
        "operation-id": "01"
      }
    },

      "source": "events_in_headers",
      "vhost": "/",
      "destination": "events_queue_02",
      "destination_type": "queue",
      "routing_key": "#",
      "arguments": {
        "x-match": "all",
        "operation-id": "02"
      }
    },


      "source": "events_in_headers",
      "vhost": "/",
      "destination": "events_queue_others",
      "destination_type": "queue",
      "routing_key": "#",
      "arguments": {
        "x-match": "all",
        "operation-id": ""
      }
    }
```

My idea is to receive when header `operation id = 01` on queue 01, when o`peration id = 02` on queue 02 and when operation id does not exist or is any other like 03, 04, 05, it will be received on the `events_queue_others`. At the moment this is working for when operation-id=01 or operation-id=02 but I'm failing to make the redirect to the default queue. Any idea?

Comment: Are the operation id values possible limited (do you have up to 99, more, less)? And could you use an alternate exchange otherwise?

Comment: @Olivier no they are not limited, but I used the dead letters + alternate exchange solution and it worked